# Recyclerview shows exception in second time while store image in imageview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having problem with recycler view. I have a recycler view containing an image and two text views.There are four items inside the recyclerview. First when the app starts there is a default image by clicking on which an image can be changed either from camera of gallery. But when i click on any image for second time there is  null point exception.

You can see my code below

This is my interface:

```
public interface OnDataItemClickListener {
void onDataClick(KycModel data, int position);
```

}

Main activity:

```
searchedItem.add(new KycModel(defaultDraw, "Signature", "his is the section where owners details are available."));
    searchedItem.add(new KycModel(defaultDraw, "Photograph", "his is the section where owners details are available."));
    searchedItem.add(new KycModel(defaultDraw, "Citizenship", "his is the section where owners details are available."));
    searchedItem.add(new KycModel(defaultDraw, "Passport", "2his is the section where owners details are available."));

itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    kycAdapter = new KycAdapter(searchedItem);
    itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(kycAdapter);

 kycAdapter.setOnDataItemClickListener(new OnDataItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataClick(KycModel data, int position) {

            p = position;
            selectImage();
        }
    });
```

Adapter class

```
 private OnDataItemClickListener onDataItemClickListener;
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final KycModel kycModel = kycList.get(position);
    holder.imgItems.setImageBitmap(kycModel.getItemImage());
    holder.txtItemName.setText(kycModel.getItemName());
    holder.txtItemDescription.setText(kycModel.getItemDescription());
    holder.imgItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onDataItemClickListener.onDataClick(kycModel, position);
        }
    });

public void setOnDataItemClickListener(OnDataItemClickListener onDataItemClickListener){
    this.onDataItemClickListener = onDataItemClickListener;

}
```

I am having null pointer exception on second time in the code

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onDataItemClickListener.onDataClick(kycModel, position);
        }
    });
```

of the adapter class. Can somebody please help?

Comment: please add error log

Comment: @Sayem null pointer exception sir                                        

 Process: com.example.sudeepbajracharya.kycsecond, PID: 16421
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.sudeepbajracharya.kycsecond.OnDataItemClickListener.onDataClick(com.example.sudeepbajracharya.kycsecond.KycModel, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sudeepbajracharya.kycsecond.KycAdapter$1.onClick(KycAdapter.java:42)

Comment: your code looks good to me. what is happening in selectImage() function. did you reinitialize the adapter in there? please update your post with that function.